# I can't read json file with FileReader in vue 3;

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, filereader

Im want to display the keys of the object of a json file imported in the v-file-input tag, and i tried to use FileReader for it but it also gives me the same error:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
```

This Is my code:

```js
<template>
<v-file-input accept=".json" v-model="selectedFile" label="Application's Data File"></v-file-input>
<v-btn class="my-3 ml-10" v-if="validated" @click="validate">Validate</v-btn>
</template>
<script setup>
const selectedFile = ref();
const validated = ref(true);
const validate = () => {
    const file = selectedFile instanceof FileList ? selectedFile[0] : selectedFile;
    if (file) {       
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            console.log(e.target.result);
            const content = e.target.result;
            try {
                const jsonObject = JSON.parse(content);
                console.log(jsonObject); // This is the parsed JSON object
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Invalid JSON file:", error);
            }
        };
        reader.readAsText(selectedFile);
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

- `selectedFile` is a ref, so `selectedFile instanceof FileList` will always be false
- VFileInput's [`modelValue`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-file-input/#events-update:modelValue) uses `File[]`, so checking against FileList will not work
- `reader.readAsText(selectedFile)` reads the ref, but you want to read `file`

So this gives you:

```
  const validate = () => {
    const fileList = selectedFile.value // <--- unwrap ref
    const file = Array.isArray(fileList) ? fileList[0] : fileList // <---- check if array (shouldn't be necessary)

    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = e => {
        console.log(e.target.result)
        const content = e.target.result
        try {
          const jsonObject = JSON.parse(content)
          console.log(jsonObject) // This is the parsed JSON object
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Invalid JSON file:', error)
        }
      }
      reader.readAsText(file) // <---- pass in extracted file
    }
  }
```

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided, the issue seems to be with the usage of `selectedFile` in the `reader.readAsText(selectedFile)` line.

The `readAsText` method expects a `Blob` object as its parameter, but `selectedFile` is not a `Blob` object. It appears that `selectedFile` is either an instance of `FileList` or a single `File` object.

To fix the issue, you should pass the correct parameter to `readAsText`. If `selectedFile` is an instance of `FileList`, you can access the first file using `selectedFile[0]`. If `selectedFile` is a single `File` object, you can directly pass it to `readAsText`.

Here's the updated code:

```html
<template>
  <v-file-input accept=".json" v-model="selectedFile" label="Application's Data File"></v-file-input>
  <v-btn class="my-3 ml-10" v-if="validated" @click="validate">Validate</v-btn>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const selectedFile = ref();
const validated = ref(true);

const validate = () => {
  const file = selectedFile instanceof FileList ? selectedFile[0] : selectedFile;
  if (file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      console.log(e.target.result);
      const content = e.target.result;
      try {
        const jsonObject = JSON.parse(content);
        console.log(jsonObject); // This is the parsed JSON object
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Invalid JSON file:", error);
      }
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
};
</script>
```

By passing `file` instead of `selectedFile` to `readAsText`, the error should be resolved, and the code should be able to read the JSON file correctly.

Comment: i've tried it before but the same error occurs